# How to check if value from one column has multiple values from another column and based on the result how to update\remove data correctly?

Tags: postgresql

I have such table `partner_stockrecord`:

```
"id"|"partner_sku"|"partner_id"
1      sku1          1
2      sku1          2

3      sku2          1
4      sku2          2
5      sku2          3

6      sku3          1
```

I need to have the next query logic:

1. if the same `partner_sku` has both `partner_id = 2` and `partner_id = 3` -> remove row with `partner_id = 2` (in order to keep just `partner_id = 3` in DB), i.e `sku2` has both `partner_id` = `2` and `3`, how to remove the row where `id = 4` in this case.
2. if `partner_sku` has just `partner_id = 2`, set `partner_id = 3`, i.e. `sku` has `partner_id` = `2` and does not have `3`.

I know, how to update\set the value with condition:

```
UPDATE partner_stockrecord
SET partner_id = 3
WHERE partner_id = 2;
```

but I do not know, how to write a complex query which can check different `partner_id` for the same `partner_sku`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists( select something *from the same table* with the same sku)`:

---

```
DELETE FROM partner_stockrecord del
WHERE del.partner_id = 2
AND EXISTS (
     SELECT 11 FROM partner_stockrecord x
     WHERE x.partner_sku = del.partner_sku
     AND x.partner_id = 3
     );
```

---

After that, you still have to do the update step with a statement like the one in your question.